# Why are my httpd mpm_prefork processes being reaped so quickly?

Tags: apache-2.2, mpm-prefork

[EDIT]

Bad question, mostly - see my answer

[/EDIT]

We've got a system running RHEL6, x64.  We are using a local installation of apache 2.2.22 from source.  we serve primarily:

1. mod_perl applications (with a local installation of perl 5.16.0)
2. tomcat applications proxied with mod_jk

**Here is some context; the main question is below.**

All of this talks to an Oracle backend.

We are having issues with Oracle becoming unresponsive.  We think this is because we're hitting the maximum process limit in oracle.  We've upped the process limit, but now we are hitting memory pressure on the oracle server.  We have tons of oracle sessions sitting idle.    I can trace a bunch of them back to the httpd processes.

We have mod_perl's Apache::DBI start up a new connection to the database with each httpd child that's spawned.  We are concerned that these are not always getting closed out properly when the httpd's exit...and the httpd's are exiting *very* frequently.  I know that it would be good to modify the mod_perl applications to use some better form of db connection pooling; we plan to pursue that but would like to solve our immediate problem sooner.

**So here's the main question.**

We are using the prefork MPM.

*The apache child processes are lasting at most a few minutes*.  Log analysis shows that each one is serving fewer than 50 clients before exiting; the last request each child serves is `OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0` on some sort of internal connection; I'm under the impression that this is a "ping" from the master process.

I've adjusted the MPM config as follows.  I didn't want to raise MinSpareServers too high, because, after all, i'm trying to minimize the number of sessions to oracle.

```
MinSpareServers       5
MaxSpareServers       30
MaxClients            150
MaxRequestsPerChild   10000
```

Right now we're serving 250-300 requests per minute.

We've got 21 httpd's running, the eldest (other than the master, owned by root) being 3 minutes old.

This rate of reaping of the apache children really seems excessive.  What could be causing it?

Apache was built with:

```
  $ ./configure --prefix=/opt/apache --with-ssl=/usr/lib --enable-expires --enable-ext-filter --enable-info --enable-mime-magic --enable-rewrite --enable-so --enable-speling --enable-ssl --enable-usertrack --enable-proxy --enable-headers --enable-log-forensic
```

Apache config info:

```
% /opt/apache/bin/httpd -V
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 23 2012 22:30:13
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.4.1
Compiled using: APR 1.4.5, APR-Util 1.4.1
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/opt/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/opt/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="logs/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

modules are compiled into apache rather than shared libs:

```
% /opt/apache/bin/httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_authn_file.c
  mod_authn_default.c
  mod_authz_host.c
  mod_authz_groupfile.c
  mod_authz_user.c
  mod_authz_default.c
  mod_auth_basic.c
  mod_ext_filter.c
  mod_include.c
  mod_filter.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_log_forensic.c
  mod_env.c
  mod_mime_magic.c
  mod_expires.c
  mod_headers.c
  mod_usertrack.c
  mod_setenvif.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_proxy.c
  mod_proxy_connect.c
  mod_proxy_ftp.c
  mod_proxy_http.c
  mod_proxy_scgi.c
  mod_proxy_ajp.c
  mod_proxy_balancer.c
  mod_ssl.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_mime.c
  mod_status.c
  mod_autoindex.c
  mod_asis.c
  mod_info.c
  mod_cgi.c
  mod_negotiation.c
  mod_dir.c
  mod_actions.c
  mod_speling.c
  mod_userdir.c
  mod_alias.c
  mod_rewrite.c
  mod_so.c
```

One final note - the red hat httpd, apr, and perl packages are all installed, but ldd shows that none of those libraries are linked with the running httpd.

Comment: By 'Oracle backend' you mean database? Is the code using persistent connections; and is a connection pool in place if so?

Comment: Yes, i mean an oracle database.  Some of our legacy code is not using a connection pool, it's opening a new db connection each time an httpd process starts.  Fixing that is on the list but understanding the prefork behavior seems more short-term attainable.

Comment: Outside of setting the Apache KeepAlive directive; prefork is all about rapid connection spawning and teardown.

Comment: prefork is all about keeping children alive as long as practical, to avoid the high cost of starting processes.  The prefork documentation even suggests setting MaxRequestsPerChild to 0, which is infinite.  I've run plenty of servers before and this is unusual behavior.

Comment: MaxRequestsPerChild 0 is a good way to hold onto memory leaks; I've always felt disagreement with that suggestion and have seen poorly run PHP sites bring prefork to it's knees with that setting. A high value, sure; but it should clean up after itself after a while.

With java using persistent connections as described, I'd say that's _it_. At 5RPS (300/min = 5Reqs/S) - prefork is likely not the culprit but improper DB connection handling via tomcat/Java.

Comment: You're right of course that it is a balancing act.  Given that I'm running some mod_perl apps, I am concerned about memory leaks, so I don't configure my servers with maxrequestsperchild 0; i use 10000 (see above).  The whole point of my question is that even with MRPC set to 10k, each child is exiting after <50 requests.  Often <10 requests.  And always after the "ping" OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0 request from the master process.  I provided all the info about my oracle setup for context; sorry if it is confusing the question.  I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

aaargh

the answer in this case turns out to be that i *hadn't* configured apache with those maxrequestsperchild, minspareservers, and maxspareservers options.

I modified a config file that I believed was `Include`d in the primary file, but wasn't. New to this site, and crufty old config.  sigh.

So, the behavior I describe is the compiled-in default (i triple checked; it is not getting set anywhere else).  The documentation suggests that these are the compiled-in defaults:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestsperchild

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/prefork.html

```
MaxRequestsPerChild 10000
MaxSpareServers 10
MinSpareServers 5
```

I think the behavior I saw was not consistent with these defaults.  I'll file a bug with apache.

I guess this is still a useful question to leave on the site, because the default behavior doesn't match the documentation.  If others disagree I'll gladly close my question.

Comment: I went ahead and installed those specific config entries (matching the defaults) to see what happened.  I saw the same behavior.  It is really counterintuitive.  I guess it really depends on how frequently the master httpd checks the traffic level and reaps its children.